# Subtract values within same column of n rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have one column matrix with n rows. I want difference between row 2 and row 1, then row 3 from row 2, and so on. I should have a new matrix with n-1 rows. I am using Matlab.

```
    513083
    513386
    513662
    513939
    514213
    514471
    514727
    514979
    515225
```

I tried this: `for x = 1:(numel(maxtab(:,1))-1) difference = maxtab(x+1,1) - maxtab(x,1); end` but I don't get the matrix. I want to avoid for loops because they slow down the process. Any suggestions. Im trying to do away with Excel because of its limitations on rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`diff()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html).

Comment: Thansk - I figured there should be a built in function for that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're looking for, but it sounds like `diff` might do the trick:

```
 mat = [513083
    513386
    513662
    513939
    514213
    514471
    514727
    514979
    515225];
K>> diff(mat)

ans =

   303
   276
   277
   274
   258
   256
   252
   246
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `diff` is your antural choice for this task you may also do it "by hand"

```
>> difference = maxtab(2:end) - maxtab(1:end-1);
```